# Swift: NSTimer Alternative

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nstimer

I've made a flappy bird clone, but when trying to implement pause functionality, I've come across issues with my NSTimer, which is spawning the pipes.

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(moveSpeed, target: self, selector: Selector("makePipes"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

As NSTimers can't be paused, within the makePipes() function I've implemented a simple if-statement, checking whether the game is paused or not, and if it is, not spawning new pipes. However, the gap between each series of pipes is then inconsistent, due to the timer still firing during the paused state.

Also, when transitioning to the game state from the menu, the timer fires off-time, creating the first two pipes in quick succession.

Is there any alternative to the NSTimer to handle this functionality?

Comment: Oh goody, the world needs more "flappy bird" clones, we have to catch up to the sheer quantity of "2048" clones. Sorry, couldn't resist :-)

Comment: Why can't you stop the timer and again start it when play resumes ?

Comment: Yes, as @MidhunMP said, just stop the timer when you pause and schedule a new one when play resumes

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the timer calling the `func invalidate()` when your game is paused, and then restart it when your game is un-paused.

Update:

You can add a second timer that fires at the difference from the next fire and the time of  pause, the second timer should fire the first timer and then reset the first timer to the initial time.

Steps:

1. Add lets say a timer that fires every 2 seconds
2. When game is paused, calculate the time interval from the `timer.fireDate` and `timeOfPause`, that should be `intervalTillNextTrigger`
3. Add a second `afterPauseTimer` that triggers at `intervallTillNextTrigger` and should not repeat
4. When the `afterPauseTimer` is called, trigger the first timer with `timer.fire()`, invalidate `timer`, because `timer.fire()` will not interrupt it's regular firing schedule, add `timer` again with 2 seconds firing interval and invalidate `afterPauseTimer`.

see code below:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  swft ios
//
//  Created by Marius Fanu on 30/12/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Marius Fanu. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer: NSTimer!

    var isPaused = false
    var isAfterPause = false
    var intervalTillNextTrigger: NSTimeInterval = 0
    var afterPauseTimer: NSTimer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: Selector("timerTriggerd"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
        timer.fire()
    }

    @IBAction func pauseButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        var now = NSDate()
        println("now = \(now)")

        if isPaused == true {
            if isAfterPause {
                isAfterPause = false
                afterPauseTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: intervalTillNextTrigger, target: self, selector: Selector("timerAfterIntervalTrigger"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
                NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(afterPauseTimer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
            }

            timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: Selector("timerTriggerd"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
        }
        else {
            isAfterPause = true
            intervalTillNextTrigger = timer.fireDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(now)
            println("till next trigger \(intervalTillNextTrigger)")
            timer.invalidate()
            timer = nil
        }

        isPaused = !isPaused
    }

    func timerTriggerd() {
        NSLog("Triggerd!")
    }

    func timerAfterIntervalTrigger() {
        println("reset timer")
        timer.fire()
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = nil

        timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: Selector("timerTriggerd"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

        afterPauseTimer.invalidate()
        afterPauseTimer = nil
    }

}
```

Comment: The same issue would arise. For example: every 2 seconds it fires. it's almost about to fire, let's say 0.5 seconds away from firing, 1.5 seconds since the last fire. We pause the game, invalidate the timer. We then start a new timer, waiting another 2 seconds before firing, it's now been 3.5 seconds since the last fire, thus creating the inconsistency.